# How display shadow only when scrolled down

Tags: css

On the Google Play Console developer website they have a div with a line at the bottom.

At this line there is no shadow at start. But when you scroll down the page it displays this shadow: `box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #999;`

And when you scroll back to the top the shadow is removed.

How is this done?

It looks like this at start:

[image]

And when you scroll down the shadow is displayed:

[image]

Comment: There is a similar question with good answers, adapt it to your needs. Here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/75814425](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75814425)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about CSS in html way, this can be done by JS detecting scroll event, and then add in the `box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #999;`

Use javascript to detect a distance of the viewport and decide how you want to change

Please tell if you just want the theory or you want to share your code to discuss?

Comment: And how would you remove the shadow again when you are scrolled back to the top?

Comment: yes, just use the same concept in reverse, when the distance is detected back to certain point you can us js to remove it. The most efficient way is to use a class, create a class, e.g. .addBoxShadow, and use it to add or remove depends on the js event